# Remove parent element after Success in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for a remove element after success.
after response, remove / fadeOut the parent element which is id = remove85 on Click  .delete

I have multiple data like that.

I am tired of some method but it removes interior data

```
<div id="loadData"> 

   <div class="deteled col-lg-4 col-md-6 px-1 py-1 py-md-1" id="remove85">
       <div class="d-flex bd-highlight sdf68wf osushow">
           <div class="p-1 p-md-2 bd-highlight flex-grow-1">
               <div class="mt-1">
                   <a href="#" id="85" class="categoryicon view">view </a>
                   <a href="edit.php?id=85" class="categoryicon">Edit </a>
                   <a href="#" id="85" class="deleteI delete" > Delete</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class=" deteled col-lg-4 col-md-6 px-1 py-1 py-md-1" id="remove86">
       <div class="d-flex bd-highlight sdf68wf osushow">
           <div class="p-1 p-md-2 bd-highlight flex-grow-1">
               <div class="mt-1">
                   <a href="#" id="86" class="categoryicon view">view </a>
                   <a href="edit.php?id=86" class="categoryicon">Edit </a>
                   <a href="#" id="86" class="deleteI delete" > </a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

```
      $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        var delete_id = $(this).attr("id");

        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this item?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./delete.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    delete_id: delete_id,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    
                    $(this).closest('.deteled').attr('id').fadeOut("normal");
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: Store `this` outside ajax call i.e : `var el =  this` .Then ,inside ajax success function use `$(el).closest(".deteled").fadeOut("normal")`.

Comment: why `.attr('id')`? that gets the id of the selected element ... I don't think that's at all what you intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the id to your jquery like so:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var delete_id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(delete_id);
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this item?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "./delete.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                delete_id: delete_id,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#" + delete_id).fadeOut("normal");
            },

            error: function(data) {
                $("#" + delete_id).fadeOut("normal");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loadData"> 

   <div class="deteled col-lg-4 col-md-6 px-1 py-1 py-md-1" id="remove85">
       <div class="d-flex bd-highlight sdf68wf osushow">
           <div class="p-1 p-md-2 bd-highlight flex-grow-1">
               <div class="mt-1">
                   <a href="#" id="85" class="categoryicon view">view </a>
                   <a href="edit.php?id=85" class="categoryicon">Edit </a>
                   <a href="#" id="85" class="deleteI delete" > Delete</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class=" deteled col-lg-4 col-md-6 px-1 py-1 py-md-1" id="remove86">
       <div class="d-flex bd-highlight sdf68wf osushow">
           <div class="p-1 p-md-2 bd-highlight flex-grow-1">
               <div class="mt-1">
                   <a href="#" id="86" class="categoryicon view">view </a>
                   <a href="edit.php?id=86" class="categoryicon">Edit </a>
                   <a href="#" id="86" class="deleteI delete" > </a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

I put the `fadeOut()` on the error method so it works on my end.